# Python updating a loop

Tags: python, loops

my program takes a mathematical input and checks it for errors before proceeding, here is the part of the code I need help with:

```
expression= introduction()#just asks user to input a math expression    
operators= set("*/+-")
numbers= set("0123456789")
for i in expression:
    while i not in numbers and i not in operators:
        print("Please enter valid inputs, please try again.")
        expression= introduction()
```

Now I have set up an error loop but the problem I am having is that I don't know what to update the loop with in this scenario. Anyone?

I need something simple such as the "while True" code in the answers below. The rest are too advanced. I need something close to the code that is posted in this OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it something like this:

```
valid = operators | numbers
while True:
    expression = introduction()
    if set(expression) - valid:
        print 'not a valid expression, try again'
    else: 
        break
```

You only want to call `introduction()` once per bad `expression`.  The way you do it now, you are calling `introduction()` for every invalid character in `expression`.

Comment: @user1716168: This *is*  a lot more simple than your code, and it's the correct way to handle this problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
expression = introduction()    
operators = {'*', '/', '+', '-'}
while any(not char.isnumeric() and char not in operators for char in expression):
    print("Please enter valid inputs, please try again.")
    expression = introduction()
```

Comment: I cannot utilize "import", "any", and "char" commands. I am limited to lists, and string manipulators, and the other most basic stuff. The other guy's way works... At least for operator input but not for numeric input...

Comment: `any` is a built-in function. Why can't you use it? Also, `char` is just a variable name, not a command.

Comment: @user1716168, as Tim pointed out, `any` is a builtin function. I don't understand why you can't use that (unless you are modifying its value for some weird reason). Anyway, I simplified the code a bit.